# What does the START_MANUAL status code mean in Oozie?

Tags: oozie

I've got a java action that's been suspended for 5 days with this status, and I don't know what oozie wants me to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that there was an error. And possibly multiple retries if you have retries configured. When retries are configured, after the first error the job goes to START_RETRY and Oozie retries automatically.

After the maximum number of retries is reached, the flow goes to state START_MANUAL. In that state, Oozie assumes that you will intervene and either fix the error and resume the job or kill the job.

There is a little more info in the documentation: http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a18_User-Retry_for_Workflow_Actions_since_Oozie_3.1